# Can there be two bounties to the same question by two people?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

Can there be two bounties to the same question by two people (including the asker)?

Example 1:

- The asker of the question gives 100 rep. Bounty & some outsider gives 150 rep. Bounty to the same question
- Thus, the asker has the privilege to reward 100 rep. to anyone, let's say they rewards person y
- The outsider also has the privilege to reward his/her *50 rep. to anyone, including person y

Example 2:

- Some outsider named o1 gives 100 rep. Bounty & some outsider named o2 gives 150 rep. Bounty to the same question.
- Thus, o1 has the privilege to reward 100 rep. To anyone, let’s say he/she rewards person y.
- The o2 also has the privilege to reward his/her 150 rep. To anyone including person y.

It need not be two bounties by two people, it can be three bounties by three people, or even in general x bounties by x people

If not, I wish this feature comes soon.

Comment: [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) - *"Questions may only have one active question bounty at any given time."*

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple bounties on the same post, just not at the same time

Comment: Please stop using inline code formatting for things that are not code. That is an abuse of the formatting, and it makes your posts much more difficult to read. (I see Larnu has already submitted an edit correcting this.) Inline code formatting is *not* meant to emphasize text; it is only for code. If you want to emphasize something, set it in bold or italics.

Comment: I honestly went ahead and removed all the emphasis in the question; due to the volume of emphasis most of the text was being emphasis meaning that the effect of the emphasis is lost. If you do need to use emphasis use it *sparingly* and only emphasize the words that really **need** it.

Comment: "*If not I wish this feature comes soon.*" the big question is: why? Perhaps you could [edit] and explain the situation where this is useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to have multiple bounties running on the same question concurrently (i.e., at the same time). However, additional bounties can always be set *later* on a question, once an earlier bounty has expired.

The purpose of a bounty is to "feature" the question: you "pay" some of your hard-earned reputation for the privilege of getting the question highlighted by the system in order to attract additional attention to it—and, hopefully, an answer! Therefore, it would not make sense to have two bounties running concurrently, as there would be no benefit to the second bounty over the first bounty. The first bounty already "featured" the question, making the second bounty a complete waste. As such, the system doesn't let any user set a bounty on a question when there is already an active bounty on that question, and there is no need for or benefit in adding such a feature.

Comment: I have already marked this as an answer but still, *"The first bounty already "featured" the question, making the second bounty a complete waste."*, the second bounty does not get wasted, it increases more attraction towards question, right? (100+150=250rep.=more attraction than just 100rep.)

Comment: No, higher bounty amounts don't attract any more attention. All bountied questions are weighted equally.

Comment: *"higher bounty amounts don't attract any more attention."* - By the system, users may spend more time on them however. - - - *"All bountied questions are weighted equally"* - Initially, older bounties are still higher up the list and may get more attention

Comment: @CodyGray I am trying to be not rude but still *"No, higher bounty amounts don't attract any more attention."*, Well then why do Stack Overflow have options to bounty a question anywhere from 50 to 500, why don't we set the bounty option limited to just 50?

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu The reason for the higher bounty amounts is that it costs more each time you feature a question. The cost scales up each time you want more attention.